# Node.js: mongoose .populate() is not showing data

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I am trying to show data from database. I have 3 Schema, combined all of them in one. But, the combined data is not showing. I have attached my 3 Schema.

async-wait is working fine with try-catch, that seem clean to me. I have also tried to follow [mongoose populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html/) . Both returns the same result.

Need to mention: i am a newbie. So, don't have good idea about best practices to follow.

Book Schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema   = mongoose.Schema;

const BookSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type     : String,
        required : [true, 'Book Title is Required'],
        max      : 100,
        min      : 5,
        trim     : true,
        lowercase: true
    },
    author: {
        type    : Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref     : 'Author',
        required: [true, 'Author is Required']
    }
    genre: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref : 'Genre'
    }]
}, { collection : 'book', timestamps: true });

BookSchema
.virtual('url')
.get(() => {
    return 'book/' + this._id;
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Book', BookSchema);
```

Author Schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema   = mongoose.Schema;

const AuthorSchema = new Schema({
    firstName: {
        type     : String,
        required : [true, 'First Name is Required'],
        max      : 100,
        min      : 5,
        trim     : true,
        lowercase: true
    },
    lastName: {
        type     : String,
        required : [true, 'Last Name is Required'],
        max      : 100,
        min      : 5,
        trim     : true,
        lowercase: true
    }
}, { collection : 'author', timestamps: true });

AuthorSchema
.virtual('name')
.get(() => {
    return this.firstName + this.lastName;
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Author', AuthorSchema);
```

Genre Schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema   = mongoose.Schema;

const GenreSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type     : String,
        required : [true, 'Genre Name is Required'],
        max      : 100,
        min      : 3,
        trim     : true,
        lowercase: true
    }
}, { collection : 'genre', timestamps: true });

module.exports = mongoose.model('Genre', GenreSchema);
```

Book Controller:

```
exports.bookList = async(req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const bookList = await Book.find({}).populate('author').exec();

        res.render('./book/index', { title: 'Book List', bookList: bookList});
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
    }
};
```

index.pug:

```
ul
    each book in bookList
        li 
            a(href=book.url) #{book.title}
            |  (#{book.author.name})

    else
        li  No book Has Been Listed Yet...!
```

1. URL is not appending the id
2. Author data is not showing
3. If i use .populate(), then. it is showing (Nan)
4. If i do not use populate, it is returning nothing

Expected output:
[apes and angels](http://localhost:3000/book/454356631)(John)

The current output:
[apes and angels](http://localhost:3000/book/undefined)(NaN)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following code. I think, it will work

```
exports.bookList = async(req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const bookList = await Book.find({}).populate('author').exec((error, list) => list);

        res.render('./book/index', { title: 'Book List', bookList: bookList});
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
    }
};
```

Comment: Showing the following error: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: @tanjiya can you please console.log the error inside the exec function before returning the result. Like this: exec((error, list) => {console.log(error); return list;}) and let me know the error (if any)

Comment: that is returning 500 and null

Comment: So, you are getting null for the error? If so, your query is executing perfectly. You might have some error in res.render.
500 means the internal server error. It is not associated with the query. Also please console.log the list param and see what is inside.

Comment: console.log(bookList) is returning the data in console.

Comment: Ok, so your query is working file. There is a problem with the redirection.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201405/discussion-between-gypsycoder-and-tanjiya).

Comment: Can you add your bookList console output here

Comment: Replied in chat. Pleas take a look.

Answer (score 1):

In my query, i had just needed to add callback like:

```
exports.bookList = async(req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const bookList = await Book.find({}).populate('author').exec((err, bookList) => {
            if (err) return bookInstanceList;

            // console.log(bookList);

            res.render('./book/index', { title: 'Book List', bookList: bookList});
        });

    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
    }
};
```

The main problem was with arrow function in Schema's. I have used arrow function to get the object. But, arrow function don't work with object. Here is the reference: [medium](https://medium.com/tfogo/advantages-and-pitfalls-of-arrow-functions-a16f0835799e)